# Android Studio: Most activity code templates not available

Tags: templates, android-activity, android-studio, code-templates

I have removed and installed Android Studio to 0.5.2, updated all my JDK's and basically started from scratch after abandoning development for a while.

I have seen that there are many code templates that a lot of new videos dealing with Android Studio have; however, I don't have them.

**How do I get them and install them if needed?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is a Preview product (not-yet-beta) and is under heavy active development. There are canary channel releases almost every week. 0.5.2 was released back in mid March and the other templates that you see have been added since that time. If you want to switch to the canary channel and update to the latest canary build (0.5.9, released last week) then you can follow the directions here to do so: http://tools.android.com/preview-channel#TOC-Android-Studio-Previews